# Как сделать что бы программа выполнялась определенное время

Tags: python

Например, у меня есть цикл:

```
while True:
    print(1)
```

Как я могу сделать, чтобы он выполнялся 30 секунд, а после 30 секунд он останавливался, и запускался другой цикл?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293269/how-would-i-stop-a-while-loop-after-n-amount-of-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import time
howLongToRun = 30 #30 seconds
timeout = time.time() + howLongToRun 
while True:
    print(1)
    if time.time() > timeout:
        break
# you other loop:
...
```

Comment: Лучше воспользоваться специальными библиотеками или внешними средствами, потому что проверять каждую итерацию условие очень медленно

Comment: @вася библиотеками? приведите пример...

Comment: [interruptingcow](https://pypi.org/project/interruptingcow/)

Answer (score 0):

[`pip3 install interruptingcow`](https://pypi.org/project/interruptingcow/) (thanks @вася)

```
from interruptingcow import timeout

try:
    with timeout(30, exception=RuntimeError):
        while True:
            print(1)
except RuntimeError:
    pass
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно с модулем `time`:

```py
from time import sleep

while True:
    print(1);
    sleep(30); #30 секунд
```

`sleep` - замораживает программу на 30 секунд.